# CSS3 Animation with AngularJS not sliding correctly in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, css, firefox, angularjs-ng-repeat, css-animations

I made a CSS3 animation connected to an `ng-repeat` which then shows an `inline-list` with Bootstrap3, I  limited the number of maximum 3 of the list showing and I have some little issues with appears mostly in Firefox (believe it or not IE11 is without issues, wow I was surprised). 

I have 2 buttons (previous/next) and when I click the Next button then the animation of sliding from left to right start to do his job, but in Firefox when clicking multiple times, it seems that the animation only works on 2/3 of the list (basically the last item on the right always show up first without even sliding while the others are sliding from left to right). It's a little hard to explain other than that, but if you try the example in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qVvzvxRcf06vnclXMICu) you will see the effect.

As I said this problem only occurs, so far, only in Firefox and seems ok in Chrome and IE11. 

Again here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qVvzvxRcf06vnclXMICu)

My AngularJS controller code

```
<ul class="list-inline quotes">
  <li ng-repeat="quote in vm.marketDisplayedQuotes | limitTo:3" class="{{vm.animationClass}} quotes quote-{{$index}}">
        <span class="quote-name">{{quote.name}}</span> 
        <span class="quote-last">{{quote.last}}</span> 
        <span class="quote-change-percent {{quote.direction}}">{{quote.changePercent}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and then the Left to Right code for the CSS animation

```
/* Left to Right */
.animation-lr.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-out all;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-out all;
  transition: 1s ease-out all;

  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%,0);
  -o-transform: translate(-100%,0);
  transform: translate(-100%,0);
}

.animation-lr.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: 0s ease-out all;
  -o-transition: 0s ease-out all;
  transition: 0s ease-out all;

  -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
  -o-transform: translate(0,0);
  transform: translate(0,0);
}

.animation-lr.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
  -o-transform: translate(0,0);
  transform: translate(0,0);
}

.animation-lr.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(100%,0);
  -o-transform: translate(100%,0);
  transform: translate(100%,0);
}
```

You can see the effect in a print screen I made from the plunker, "CAC" is completely on right (and is fixed there and is not moving), not being at all part of the sliding animation effect
[image: Right Text not sliding]

Comment: It works well for me on FF.

Comment: Don't you have the last one on the right that always appear before all others and does not move? I should try it on my other computer just to make sure

Comment: Nopes. I see it working as fine as it does on Chrome..

Comment: That is strange, I actually confirmed that I get the same bad effect on my laptop too. Both my computers not working correctly though I use Firefox Beta 33 on both. I am posting an image too, you can see CAC shows up on the right and not being part of sliding effect

Comment: I can see the problem, but strangely enough it disappears once I inspect the list element with Firebug. After I close Firebug the problem pops up again.

Comment: Ok at least, I'm not crazy...haha.. I included a print screen, though you also now see the effect yourself

Comment: @Bogdan yeah exactly that is why i did work for me i guess, i had firebug open. I see now what the issue is...

Comment: Even with Firebug open, I find the behavior inconsistent. For the first 2 or 3 clicks on "Next", it doesn't happen and then randomly happens once.

Comment: I seriously think that it's related to a timing issue, which is well known that we often have to add a setTimeout especially with Firefox. But still, I would not know where to add it using `ngAnimate` and I expect that it's already somehow part of the `ngAnimate` code.

Comment: @ghiscoding I tried to implement a version w/ timeout and it is still giving the same result

Comment: I'm starting to believe it has to do with the way the ng-repeat is running. I changed the styles to not use transform, just in case it was a bug with that, and the same affect is happening. http://plnkr.co/edit/qVvzvxRcf06vnclXMICu?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I updated the script to the newest version of libraries, and it work well.

`jquery: 2.1.1
angular: 1.3.0
angular-animate: 1.3.0`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1-rc2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0-beta.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0-beta.13/angular-animate.js"></script>`

I added those changes and this is the result. You can see it in this plunker link.

http://embed.plnkr.co/Ry7WTBPZKxeHhL1V5jKy/preview

Comment: Wow ok I know you really want the +50 and I know that I said I prefer to be up to date but I also mentioned `1.2.2x`, now on the other hand you are truly giving me a working solution (kind of) though it's still an unrelease version `1.3 RC3` as of now... so here's the deal, I can't give you the 50 points because it's not an official release (which is what I wanted and also because 1.3 breaks some of my code, though I didn't specify that in my question), so I would still prefer a working solution with `1.2.2x` I will wait, but if really is that is the only alternative, I might accept it

Comment: The reason for my help was not for a score, but to help giving you a solution to solve your problem. Because that's the idea, help each developers. I am not an architect javascript, but every day I learn more by helping others. But thanks for your score. God bless you

Comment: Again thanks for your help, I did not want to offend you, I truly appreciate the time you took to help with my problem. I also think like you that answering questions, and sometime asking questions does help each other a lot, so I strongly agree with you... with that being said, I really wish to find a solution with current release versions, the offer of higher score helps for visibility and I really hope to have something working with these `1.2.x` version. Thanks a lot for your help and comments

Comment: Since I did not get better answers (with `Angular 1.2.x`), I'll accept your answer as a valid choice for future implementation of `1.3.x` when they get it release. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You better use angular-ui library that will work very well with carasoul, i was myself having this issue

Answer (score 0):

I forked your source code to give you a proposal of how you could do it.
Your problem is probably in the versions of the libraries you are using.

Solution: 
 1. Change libraries versión.
 2. Add jquery library for angular bestperformance
 3. Add -moz- prefixed to css properties animation

`-moz-transform`
`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.0rc3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

I added those changes and this is the result. You can see it in this plunker link. I Hope this helps.

http://embed.plnkr.co/Ry7WTBPZKxeHhL1V5jKy/

Comment: your problem is probably in the versions of the libraries you are using

Comment: I would not want to use such an old version of Angular, you're basically pointing to `1.2.0 RC3` which is way too old, not even a released version... I would rather have something working with latest version of `1.2.2x` and as for jQuery, yes I do use jQuery (up to date) in my real app, and finally adding `-moz-transform` does not make any changes as I believed Mozilla removed the `-moz` prefix from their CSS need long time ago. All that being said, if something is wrong in AngularJS or Animate code, then Angular core devs need to be aware. Thanks for you help

Comment: Good morning God bless you. I know the versions your are using are newer than the versions I am using; and that´s the problem, your mozilla version is probably not behaving as you want whith the library version you are using. Remember that not all libraries versions work properly in all browser versions. That's why I include those version. I tested your libraries version your are using with my mozilla version and it doesnt work.

Comment: Thanks for your help again, but considering that in theory we should always be up to date with our tools and application version, I still want this to work with AngularJS & Animate version which are up to date. Which the problem is really with Angular and/or Animate libraries, then I will have to go advise the group which are responsible. I appreciate your help, but unfortunately cannot accept the answer as it is with old version... hope you understand... again thanks for your help!